# Amazon EC2 instance of Windows Server 2012- unable to connect to simple webserver

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, tomcat, windows-server-2012, curl

Using Amazon EC2 I have successfully launched a Windows Server 2012 instance and configured it to run a Tomcat webserver.

From within the VPS itself, I know the webserver is working because I see the Tomcat page in a web browser when I type `http://localhost:8080`.

However, I am unable to access it externally even though I've created a rule in the security group to allow incoming traffic on port 8080 from all addresses (0.0.0.0/0).

Typing 'curl -v http://ec2-54-194-6-178.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080' returns:

- About to connect() to ec2-54-194-6-178.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 8080 (#0)
- Trying 54.194.6.178...
- Operation timed out
- couldn't connect to host
- Closing connection #0 curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

I also have a Linux instance running that is using the same security group. I am able to connect to that just fine.

I don't know much about configuring Tomcat but I also added address="0.0.0.0" to the config file, server.xml just in case that was a potential cause.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           address="0.0.0.0" />
```

Any ideas how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked windows firewall?

Comment: @boburob I figured it out eventually. I was able to connect to the Tomcat web-server by turning off the Windows firewall. Was coming back here to post an update and saw your comment. Thanks, anyway.